# Why not organise all functions in a package in one file?

Tags: r

I found the following line in Hadley Wickham's book about R packages:

> While you’re free to arrange functions into files as you wish, the two extremes are bad: don’t put all functions into one file and don’t put each function into its own separate file (See [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/r.html#r-organising)).

But why? This would seem to be the two options which make most sense to me. Especially keeping just one file seems appealing to me.

#### From user perspective:

When I want to know how something works in a package I often go to the respective GitHub page and look at the code. Having functions organised in different files makes this a lot harder and I regularly end up cloning a repository just so I can search the content of all files (e.g. via `grep -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e 'function <-'`).

#### From a developer's perspective

I also don't really see the upside for developing a package. Browsing through a big file doesn't seem much harder than browsing through a small one if you employ the outline window in R Studio. I know about the Ctrl + .  shortcut but it still means I have to open a new file when working on a different function while Ctrl + . could basically do the same job if I keep just one file.

Wouldn't it make more sense to keep all functions in one single file? I know different people like to organise their projects in different ways and that is fine. I'm not asking for opinions here. Rather I would like to know if there are any real disadvantage of keeping everything in one file.

Comment: This is just personal preference. Many people like to have similar functions in the same file. You can put constructor functions for a class and their print and plot methods together, or you can put all plotting functions together. (Note that you can search directly on github just fine.)

Answer (score 1):

There is obviously not one single answer to that. One obvious question is the size of your package: If it contains only those two neat functions and a plot command, why bother organizing it in any difficult manner: Just hack it into one file and you are good to go. 
If your project is large, say you try to throw the R graphics system over and write lots and lots of functions (geoms and stats and ...) a lot of small files might be a better idea. But then, having more files than there is room for tabs in RStudio might not be such a good idea as well.
Another important question is, whether you intend to develop alone or with hundreds of people on GitHub. You might prefer to accept a change in a small file as opposed the "the one big file" that was so easy to search, back when you were alone.

The people who invented Java originally had a "one file per class" going and C# seems to have something similar. That does not mean, that those people are less clever then Hadley. It just means, that your mileage may vary and you have the right to oppose to Hadleys opinions.

Comment: I agree that version control with a couple of contributors might make it necessary to use different files. Otherwise merging commits can probably become a hug headache. Thanks, I did not think of that!

Answer (score 1):

Why not put all files on your computer in the root directory?

Ultimately if you use a file tree you are back to using everything as single entities.

Putting things that conceptually belong together into the same file is the logical continuation of putting things into directories/libraries.
If you write a library and define a function as well as some convenience wrappers around them it makes sense to put them in one file.
Navigating the file tree is made easier as you have fewer files and navigating the files is easier as you don't have all functions in the same file.

Comment: This all seems to suggest it's a better idea to use as few files as possible, which was my instinct as well. The question is though why not just keep one single file?

Comment: I was hoping my last paragraph would explain that. If you have a file with 10000 functions because you have a large package you are still going to take a while to find it. If you keep a structure with several files(and directories) it may not even require a significant amount of thought to get to the function you are looking for as you are just following the breadcrumbs